# Not able to set negative value of CGSize in @IBInspectable in swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to set shadow offset of button using @IBInspectable, but it has minimum value 0, but i want to set negative value.

```
like this  button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -10.0, height: -10.0) 
I have following code

@IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
       get {
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowRadius = newValue

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like apple choose wrong type CGSize for shadow offset. Negative size is not logical value. 
Still for solving this this particular problem we need to Interface builder allow us set negative value. So my suggested workaround is:

```
  @IBInspectable var shadowWidthOffset: CGFloat {
    get {
      return _shadowOffsetWidth
    }
    set {
      _shadowOffsetWidth = newValue
    }
  }

  @IBInspectable var shadowHeightOffset: CGFloat {
    get {
      return _shadowOffsetHeight
    }
    set {
      _shadowOffsetHeight = newValue
    }
  }

  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawRect(rect)
    ...
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(_shadowOffsetWidth, _shadowOffsetHeight)
  }
```