# How to make a shadow to top and left of image?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have added a shadow to right and bottom of an image.

The code is

```
func addShadow(image: UIImage, blursize: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
   let shadowColor = UIColor(white:0, alpha: 0.8).cgColor
   let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(image.size.width + blursize), height: Int(image.size.height + blursize), bitsPerComponent: image.cgImage!.bitPerComponent, bytesPerRow: 0, space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)!
   context.setShadow(offset: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0), blur: blursize, color: shadowColor)
   context.draw(image.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x:0,y:blursize,width:image.size.width, height: image.size.height), byTiling: false)
   return UIImage(cgImage: context.makeImiage()!)
}
```

I need to add a shadow to left and top of an image.
[image]

How can I do?

Comment: because `CGSize` cant use negative numbers, you may need to override some functions to use `CGFloat` instead for `.setShadow`, have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836278/not-able-to-set-negative-value-of-cgsize-in-ibinspectable-in-swift/39529276#39529276

Comment: @Eric, you can get an effect like this by using `UIImageView` if your only task is to display an Image with shadow, I believe you are adding this effect to UIImage because you want to save this to Photos. Can you please let me know if I'm correct or not?

Comment: Thank you for your message.
Yes. I don't want a shadow to UIImageView..

Comment: What you are currently doing is not adding a shadow to the bottom and right of the image. You're creating a shadow that has the same position as the original image, but larger (due to the blur), and which is only visible to the bottom and right because the rest is clipped. If you want the same effect you currently have, just add `2 * blurSize` instead of `blurSize` when computing the size of your `CGContext`, and set `x` to `blurSize` in your call to `context.draw`.

Comment: Thank you jcaron.